# Running VBA Excel File from different Locations at Runtime

Tags: excel, vba, networking, userform

I have developed an Accounts and Inventory System in Excel, All Data Entry, Edit, Delete is through VBA Forms. Every thing worked fine till the The biggest problem arrived, which is now my company ask me to operate same excel software from different PCs at runtime. I know the work book behaves read only when opened to another location at a time. Another idea is shared workbook but it also limits data ENTRY from win form.

Comment: One possible solution is to store all the data online and have the workbook download the data at runtime. That way you can run unlimited number of workbooks and still keep an up to date data. I use this system (on a light scale) in one of my macros.

Comment: @Andreas I was not copying you! Honestly when I wrote my answer your comment was not visible to me. I can only say great minds sync alike right1?

Comment: @GaryEvans I wrote my comment after you answered. But I did not read your answer as it was an online answer. But you are correct, great minds...

Answer (score 0):

Your best option (unless you move to Access) is a master and clients.

The master will be a store of all data, and the clients will be local to each person, a trigger will need to exist in the clients (say on form open and close) to send their content into the master. Depending on what your workbook does you may need to build mechanism like caching, syncing, and error handling.